# How to share login state between multiple IdentityServer4 clients?

Tags: c#, authentication, identityserver4, openid-connect

Say you have an IdentityServer4 that we use to log in to around 10 SPA applications.

They all log in with their own IdentityServer4 "client" technically. However, all clients point to the same business logic database of users to check for credentials (the same server in the AccountController Login endpoint). They all also use the same flow, as they are all SPA applications.

To the end users, this is annoying and they expect to log in to 1 client and automatically be logged in to all others.

I understand the hack of pretending all clients is the same client will work. But it's not good for neither analysis of what client is in use nor security.

Has anyone a safe and user friendly example solution?

Comment: strange to read about annoyed end users -- they must log in once and then get the token for each next client silently -- that's the main idea of SSO. maybe you or me missed something in the explanation? maybe consent? you can just switch it off...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.